# Newly created file gives FileNotFound until 5 seconds have passed in ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, filenotfoundexception

Been pulling my hair out with this one.

I make a blocking call that converts a docx to a pdf alongside the original file on the network share.
The call returns true representing success. I then attempt to try File.Exists on the file and get a false back. Now I used to get true back because the file does exist, so this is a problem that's cropped up the last week or so. Narrowing down the cause and/or change is what I'm trying to do.

First thing I tried was (for test purposes) putting the File.Exists in a loop and blocking to iterate the loop every second. Each loop represents one attempt, up to 10 loops or 10 seconds. What I've found is that consistently after about 5 seconds, File.Exists returns true and it can hence be accessed.

After the first File.Exists failure I've since added some extra test checks and I've found that the file is listed by Directory.GetFiles, FileIOPermission says I do have permission to it, nothing has a lock on it, and the HRESULT from Win32 when I try a File.Open is 2, or FILE_NOT_FOUND.

This is all under IIS and ASP.NET by the way. Windows authentication and impersonation turned on.

To compound the strangeness, after rebuilding (or recycling app pool) it finds it on the first attempt. All subsequent tests fail until 5 seconds pass.
Secondly, this works fine on my machine, pointing to the same file on the same UNC path and it always finds the file straight away.

I'll drop some of my test code below to help outline this

```
var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
bool found = false;
int attempt = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    if (File.Exists(targetRevision.PdfPath))
    {
        found = true;
        attempt = i;
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            var visibleFiles = Directory.GetFiles(Path.GetDirectoryName(targetRevision.PdfPath))
                .Aggregate((a, f) => a + Environment.NewLine + f);
            Logger.Log("Listing of visible files", LogTypeEnum.Debug, new Exception(visibleFiles));

            try
            {
                new System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission(
                System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermissionAccess.Read, targetRevision.PdfPath).Demand();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log("Don't appear to have access to the file.", LogTypeEnum.Debug, e);
            }
            try
            {
                using (var pdfStream = File.Open(targetRevision.PdfPath, FileMode.Open))
                {

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var hresult = Marshal.GetHRForException(e);
                var errorCode = hresult & ((1 << 16) - 1);

                Logger.Log("Can't seem to open the file. HRESULT " + hresult + ", errorCode " + errorCode, LogTypeEnum.Debug, e);
            }

            try
            {
                var lockingProcesses = FileUtil.WhoIsLocking(targetRevision.PdfPath);

                if (lockingProcesses.Any())
                {
                    Logger.Log("Listing of locking processes", LogTypeEnum.Debug, new Exception(
                    lockingProcesses
                        .Select(p => p.ProcessName)
                        .Aggregate((a, p) => a + Environment.NewLine + p)));
                }
                else
                {
                    Logger.Log("No locks found on PDF", LogTypeEnum.Debug);

                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Logger.Log("Failed to check for locking processes", LogTypeEnum.Debug, e);
            }
        }

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        // thy eyes bleed - this is debug (NOT PRODUCTION CODE)
    }
}
stopwatch.Stop();
```

Comment: Could you please post code that creates file(s) in question?

Comment: It won't help. It's a WCF service call (BasicHttpBinding) to a service that uses Aspose.Words to do the conversion. The important bit is that it's a blocking call and doesn't hold a lock to the file after it's created.

Comment: Are you sure that the wcf service only returns when the pdf is created and the file was closed?  Perhaps aspose.word or the wcf service returns before file was completely written to disk and closed.

Comment: A couple of reasons I know it runs to completion before it returns. 1. It works fine on my machine. 2. They both log to the same database, and the log entry after the pdf is converted on the wcf side happens before any of my file.exists debug codes logs

Comment: I asked that because, in the past, I used pdf converters running on Windows printer spoller. The pdf converters returned "ok" when they just sent data to spooler. But spooler required more time to finish jrunning. So, the pdf files were not ready when they returned "OK".